# How to access Meta on CustomNode using Graphene and Relay

Tags: django, graphene-python

I want to make a generic get_node_from_global_id, so I need to get the root model the query is requesting and then return a row from that table. To do this I want to use `model = getattr(Query,info.field_name).field_type.Meta.model` .

The first part, `getattr(Query,info.field_name).field_type` gets me `TableNameNode` from `Query` using `info.field_name`. But when I try to access `...Meta.model` I get an error saying that there is no attribute `Meta` on `TableNameNode`. I can see that there is a nested class `Meta` so how can I access it?

```
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType
from graphene import relay

class CustomNode(relay.Node): 
    class Meta:
        name = 'Node'

    @staticmethod
    def to_global_id(type, id):
        #returns a non-encoded ID
        return id

    @staticmethod
    def get_node_from_global_id(info, global_id, only_type=None):
        user = info.context.user
        model = getattr(Query,info.field_name).field_type.Meta.model
        #return row here...
        pass


class Query(object):
    tablename = CustomNode.Field(TableNameNode)

class TableNameNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = TableName
        interfaces = (CustomNode,)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging around [here](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/blob/08c86f3def71b1cb8aebc13026dae11982fc1ef7/graphene/relay/node.py#L74) I got the idea that I should try `._meta` to access the `Meta` nested class. I don't know the rationale behind this, but when I changed my code to `model = getattr(Query,info.field_name).field_type._meta.model` it worked.